# What's the meaning of "un-PC"?

Tags: vocabulary, slang

Yesterday, I came across the word "un-PC" while reading a book, and I couldn't find it in a dictionary. Can anybody explain it, please?

Comment: General Reference - [***PC = Political Correctness***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_correctness), and ***un-*** is just a standard prefix.

Answer (score 1):

PC can stand for 'Politically Correct'. So, un-PC is nothing but 'Not politically correct', or rather 'Politically incorrect'.

Comment: Heh, and here I thought we were talking about Apple products.

Answer (score 0):

PC is a commonly used abbreviation for Politically Correct or Political Correctness. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_correctness):

> **Political correctness** (adjectivally, **politically correct**, commonly abbreviated to **PC**) is an ordinarily pejorative term used to criticize language, actions, or policies seen as being excessively calculated not to offend or disadvantage any particular group of people in society.

So "un-PC" means **politically incorrect** as an adjective or **politically incorrectly** as an adverb.